# Is there a way to add <li> items from server under <ul> and keep ul ID as i want?

Tags: c#, html, user-controls, html-lists

First, note that im using C#.

Basically, i know i can add server controls under a ul tag which is runat=server:

***HTML:***

```
<ul id="myID" runat="server"></ul>
```

***C#:***

```
myId.Controls.Add(...);
```

but the issue is that once i add these items, the ul item has now a new generated id (such as: id=ctl00_cphMainContainer_ctl00_myID) which ruins my javascript code and also my css.

I was wondering, is there a clean way i could add my li items and keep my ul **as it is**?

Comment: you can identify the element using a syntax like `$('ul[id$="myID"]')` in javascript. This will match the ul element ending with myID and not break your code. On the server side, you can still access it with the same id.

Comment: your suggestion messes up my javascript, aint sure how to put things together with that syntax, for example: i had something like: $("#myID a"), how should that be changed to?

Comment: `$('ul[id$="myID"] a')`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your framework version, if you are sure it will not generate conflicting ids, you may try to alter the ClientIDMode of your `ul`, making it static :

```
<ul id="myID" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></ul>
```

see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx